# Semicolon in set-builder notation

Tags: math-mode, symbols

What is the best way to type ";" in the set-builder notation?

I think `\{\, x \in X \mid P(x) \,\}` is a common way to type the set-builder notation.  Someone use ":" instead of "|". Anyway, these symbols frequently used in mathematics and I feel uncomfortable when I see the ones similar to the followings (`\mid` and `\lvert` or `\colon` and `:` are overlapping).

> SL(V) = { L ∈ GL(V) | |L| = 1 } = { L : V → V : |L| = 1 }

A possible typesetting might be `\{\, x \in X \,;\, P(x) \,\}`. I'd like to ask, however, if there is a good practice like `\mid` for this. If there is another, what differs from the one that I showed? Thank you.

**Edit for clarification**  The ones use "|" or ":" are just examples to explain why I dislike it. *What I want to know* is whether there is a better way to type ";" in this context or not.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all you should define a command for the separation symbol, so that you're sure it will be uniform in the whole document.

I propose four different choices, select the one which you like most.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}
\DeclareMathOperator{\SL}{SL}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ssep}{\mid}

$\SL(V)=\{\, L\in\GL(V) \ssep \lvert L\rvert=1 \,\}=
 \{\, L\colon V\to V \ssep \lvert L\rvert=1 \,\}$

\medskip

\renewcommand{\ssep}{:}

$\SL(V)=\{\, L\in\GL(V) \ssep \lvert L\rvert=1 \,\}=
 \{\, L\colon V\to V \ssep \lvert L\rvert=1 \,\}$

\medskip

\renewcommand{\ssep}{\,;\,}

$\SL(V)=\{\, L\in\GL(V) \ssep \lvert L\rvert=1 \,\}=
 \{\, L\colon V\to V \ssep \lvert L\rvert=1 \,\}$

\medskip

\renewcommand{\ssep}{;}

$\SL(V)=\{\, L\in\GL(V) \ssep \lvert L\rvert=1 \,\}=
 \{\, L\colon V\to V \ssep \lvert L\rvert=1 \,\}$

\end{document}
```

[image: four different choices]

My choice would be for the colon or the bar.

I would *never* denote by `\lvert L\rvert` the determinant of a matrix, which would avoid problems with two consecutive bars. Using `\colon` for the symbol in map denotations prevents confusion if the colon is used.

Comment: Thank you for answer. In short, defining new command recommended for unity but there is no shortcut like `\mid`, right?

Answer (score 7):

I agree with the rest, but would just like to show what I tend to do in recent projects.

I would like the code to make more sense in it self and I want to hide the symbol.

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\SetSymbol[1][]{\nonscript\:#1\vert\allowbreak\nonscript\:\mathopen{}}
\providecommand\given{} % to make it exist
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]\{\}{\renewcommand\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]}#1}
```

Which is then used as

```
\Set{ x\in A \given x^2 \geq 3 }
```

Then in the same manner as we do with `siunitx`, the code makes sense when read aloud.

A similar construction can be used to define a probability operator with build in support for conditional probabilities.

---

Updated 2015: added `\nonscript`, `\allowbreak` and `\mathopen` to the `\SetSymbol` definition. Works better.

Comment: Thank you for providing clean way to type the set-builder notation. Though it is not directly refer to the question that I asked, I love it.

Comment: The whole idea is now just just build your symbol into the `\SetSymbol` macro, job done. Very much in the same line as the other answers.

Comment: If I want to use `:` instead of `\vert`, what should I do? Replace `\vert` by `{:}` in order to make `:` a class 0 symbol? Otherwise, i.e. replacing `\vert` by merely `:`, it would be wrong. Am I right?

Comment: @Trash just redefine `\SetSymbol` so its contents is `:`. This is the whole idea why we do it like this. I don't think you need to make it class zero (haven't checked), in that case I'd leave in the spacers, remove `#1` and replace `\very`  by `{:} `

Comment: OK, but why would you replace by `{:}` and not by `:`? Also, why would you remove `#1`? What is the purpose of `#1` which is written _before_ `\vert`?

Comment: @Thrash if you use `\Set[\Big]{...}` then `\Big` is given to `\SetSymbol` referred to by `#1` in its definition. But `:` is not a delimiter and thus `\Big:` is an error. You brought up `{:}` not me. Just note there is a difference between `{:}` and `:`, the spacing around it, `{:}` has none so may look strange

Comment: How did you get notified although I didn't use the @ symbol? One also needs to remove `\delimsize` when using a colon. Of course, I meant it in that way that `\:` stays on both sides.

Comment: No sorry, you're  right. It's sufficient to remove `#1` from the `\SetSymbol` definition.

Comment: @Thrash the owner of an answer always gets notified when someone comments on their answer

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not seem to be about TeX, rather about math, but anyways, I'll try to give some points:

- You can use vertical bar, colon or semicolon.
- However, please! **do not mix them in one paper!!!**
- For the example with funtion definition, you can do

  ```
  \{ L : L \text{ is a function } V \to V,\ \lvert L\rvert=1 \}
  ```
- I tend to use bold colon with the help of `\usepackage{bm}`, and I use `\usepackage{mathtools}`' `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`:

  ```
  \DeclarePairedDelimiterX\set[2]\lbrace\rbrace{#1 \bm: #2}
  \DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert

  ...
  \set{L}{L \text{ is a function } V \to V,\ \abs{L}=1}
  ```

[image]

Comment: Bold colon? ***No way***.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But the ones use "|" or ":" are just examples to explain why I dislike it. _What I want to know_ is whether there is a better way to type ";" in this context or not.

Comment: Also, `L \text{ is a function } V \to V` sounds awkward. Either write it all out, or use symbols all the way.