# Accented Letters

Tags: symbols, characters

I have to insert the accented letters as the following

```
P\'eclet
```

to obtain Péclet.

What code should i write to obtain Pèclet for example?

Thanks for help

Comment: you can use `\\`{e}` but also you can just use é and è directly as long as you specify the encoding eg `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: If you need to typeset the name Pèclet more than once you should consider a wrapper macro, say `\newcommand{\peclet}{P\'{e}clet}` or `\newcommand{\peclet}{Pèclet}` with the suggestion by David Carlisle of loading `inputenc`

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. Just a last question? How can i produce the accent in the first notation proposed by @DavidCarlisle ?

Comment: See also the table in the second half of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281887/5001).

Comment: do you mean how do you type `\`` ? It depends on your keyboard, on UK keyboards it is top left next to `1`

Comment: If you have Windows and you don't see the backtick on you keyboard, type `Alt+96`