# putting ^ over character in math expressions

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to achieve ^ over any letter in math formula. In normal text, it works with `\^letter`. However in my case, I am using

```
    \begin{align*}
    \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y^{i}-\^{y}^{(i)})^{2}
    \end{align*}
```

which outputs nothing on the place where y with ^ should be. What is a workaround for this or how can I achieve it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: See also [Trying to use “\~” to generate tilde symbol in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281881/5001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math accent for `^` is called `\hat`, see ["The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y^{i}-\hat{y}^{(i)})^{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]