# How to do this in latex

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How to write this formula:

[image]

How can I read symbol e?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I think you need `\hat{e}` but you chose the worst title possible.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "read symbol e"? Are you asking how to place a "hat" symbol above a lowercase letter "e"?

Comment: Did you see the posting [Trying to use “\~” to generate tilde symbol in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281881/5001)? This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281887/5001) addresses not only to tilde symbols, but "hat", "dot", "double-dot" and other symbols as well.

Answer (score 1):

coding:

```
$\hat{e}(aP,bP)= \hat{e}(P,bP)^a$
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `bP` instead of `p`?

Comment: Please use proper code markup.

Comment: -1: Answers should be self-contained, i.e. one can copy, paste and typeset them without having to write boilerplate.  Please make your answer into a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: +1 The question itself is lacking a MWE, so it would be unfair to expect a MWE in an answer

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `\left` and `\right` as well

`\hat{e}\left(aP,bP\right) = \hat{e}\left(P,bP\right)^a`

Comment: For such simple expression, I would not recommend. Maybe `\bigl( \bigr)`. But this is just opinion.

Comment: @Sigur Actually, according to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/164314), [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58641/164314) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12793/164314), `\left` and `\right` should be used sparsely.

Comment: Useful insights about the `\left` and `\right` commands. Thank you.