# Bar over letter but NOT math mode

Tags: accents

Every search I have done for this, the answer involves `\bar` or `\overline` but those are math mode and thus result in the math font being used, which often differs from the main text font.

Ēostre - note the E has a bar over it. A Pagan Goddess. If I use math mode then the upper case E is a different font than the ostre which is typographically wrong.

How, using TeXLive with pdflatex compiler, so I add a horizontal bar over a latin letter *without* using math mode?

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you give `\=E` a try yet? See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281887/5001) for more information about text-mode and math-mode commands to place various accent-like characters above and below letters [shameless self-citation alert!].

Comment: Or `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\textoverline}[1]{\ensuremath{\overline{\text{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\textoverline{A}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 5):

\=E is what I was looking for.