# What is the \v{} in $\v{x}$ stands for?

Tags: math-mode

It seems `\v` is like `\emph` or `\textbf` to represent the letter or number in other forms. But what does it stand for? Is there some other not common character transformation in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It is the letter `x` with a caron above.

Comment: `\v` is a text-mode command; it places a "v-check" or "caron" symbol above its argument (generally a single letter). `\v` should *never* be employed in math mode. Instead of `$\v{x}$`, one should write `$\check{x}`.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281887/5001) to the posting [Trying to use “\~” to generate tilde symbol in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281881/5001).

Comment: What does `\V{x}` look like? Can you provide an image?

Comment: `\V` is not defined in standard LaTeX.  Please tell us what classes and packages you are using.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36955/15925 for general techniques.

Comment: Where did you find this TeX code? Since you don’t know what it means, I presume it’s an extract you’re taking from somewhere else. Since `\V` isn’t a standard LaTeX command, it must be defined in the specific document you found it in (look for a like beginning `\newcommand[1]{V}` or similar), or one of the packages the document loads. Without seeing the rest of the documents or knowing which packages it loads, we can’t help you.

Answer (score 5):

```
http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf
```

Table 18. I believe this is what you are asking? Though it's not really $\LaTeX$ related.

[image]