# How to type bow like upper script? (like a hat but curve and upside down)

Tags: typography, superscripts, annotations

[image]

That thing ^^^.

It's similar to the $\bar{q}$ notation but I have no idea how to even search that symbol.

Comment: Try `$\breve{q}$`.

Comment: Close enough it seems? How do you find a given latex symbol when you don;t know the name?

Comment: Simply, I look for available math symbols in my LaTeX editor (WinEdt).

Comment: Either `\check{q}` or `\breve{q}` in math mode. You can look at the `accents` [tag info](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/accents/info) for more information.

Comment: See also [Trying to use “\~” to generate tilde symbol in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281881/5001)` and the associated answers.