# Write n with tilde above, as in El Nino

Tags: symbols, unicode, tilde

I'm trying to write "El Niño" in text mode within a paragraph.

I'm currently doing it like `El Ni$\mathrm{\tilde{n}}$o`, which is frankly ridiculous.

Can anybody explain how to do this more succinctly and readably?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE!  Try  `El Ni\~no`.

Comment: Type `El Niño` and you're done. If you can't type the accented letter directly, use `El Ni\~no`

Comment: Does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281887/5001) help? It lists the commands to generate tildes, hats, etc in both text and math mode.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The classic markup for the text accent would be `\~` not the math mode `\tilde` but for many years you haven't needed to use that, the above output is produced by

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

El Niño

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Spanish-specific commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Set the font (output) encodings
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Spanish-specific commands
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
Este es un breve resumen del contenido del 
documento escrito en español. El Niño es?

\end{document}
```

[image]